# what is the best way to define constant variables python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants, configuration-files

I am writing a program in python which contains many constant variables. I would like to create a file that will hold all these variables like the `.h` file in **C** that contains many `#define`. I tried to use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) however I didn't find it easy and fun to use.

Do you know a better way?

Comment: As far as configuration variables go, you can set environment variables and read them from within your code.  You could also use JSON or YAML files.

Answer (score 38):

#### Constants (in a sense) in Python 3.8+

Python 3.8 introduces the `typing.Final` type qualifier, which is used to indicate that a variable or attribute should not be reassigned, redefined, or overridden.

[PEP 591 -- Adding a final qualifier to typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/)

```py
from typing import Final

# Annotate module variables
# (with or without an explicit type, using the syntax Final[<type>])
# (type is auto-determined in absence of an explicit type)
PI: Final[float] = 3.141592654
ANSWER_TO_EVERYTHING: Final = 42


# Annotate instance variables in class bodies
# (explicit type is needed if no value is assigned)
class Point:
    x: Final[int]
    y: Final = 0

    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x


# Annotate instance variables directly
# (only allowed in __init__ methods)
class Person:
    def __init__(self, birth_year: int):
        self.birth_year: Final = birth_year
```

Linters and type checkers will show you warnings if you reassign or redefine `Final` variables. Note that there is no runtime check, so you can still run the code below.

```py
ANSWER_TO_EVERYTHING: Final = 42
ANSWER_TO_EVERYTHING = 420  # shows warning
print(ANSWER_TO_EVERYTHING)  # prints 420
```

There is also the `typing.final` decorator, which is used to restrict inheriting classes and overriding methods.

Answer (score 32):

Python does not allow constant declarations like C or C++.

Normally in Python, constants are capitalized ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) standards) which helps the programmer know it's a constant.

Ex. `MY_CONSTANT = "Whatever"`

Another valid way of doing it which I don't use but heard of, is using a method:

```
def MY_CONSTANT():
    return "Whatever"
```

Now in theory, calling `MY_CONSTANT()` acts just like a constant.

**EDIT**

Like the comments says, someone can go and change the value by calling

```
MY_CONSTANT = lambda: 'Something else'
```

but don't forget the same person can call `MY_CONSTANT = "Something else"` in the first example and change the initial value. In both cases it is unlikely but possible.

Comment: `MY_CONSTANT = lambda: 'Something else'` – Not sure why you'd bother with a "constant function", it's not any more constant.

Comment: @scharette The point is that whether you use `def` or `lambda`, you can still easily change the value of `MY_CONSTANT`; it's just a name that refers to some object, whether that object be an `int` or a `function`. Plus, the overhead of calling a function (both the lexical overhead of having to add `()` and the run-time overhead of setting up the stack frame) outweigh any perceived benefit.

Comment: `MY_CONSTANT = lambda: "new value"!` is just as easy to write as `MY_CONSTANT = "new value!"`; making it a function doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: You're right, this is not how I understood what he meant. I'm not trying to say this is a real constant, he's asking for C like constants, which doesn't exist in built-in python. My point is if someone is calling `MY_CONSTANT = lambda: 'Something else'` he really wants to change the value.

Comment: Samething goes for someone changing the constant itself in C. I mean a constant is a constant until the day someone goes around and change the inital value...

Answer (score 23):

There are no constants in Python, the way they exist in C or Java. You can imitate them by functions:

```
def FOO():
  return "foo"
```

You can wrap the function call in a property, and thus make it look like a variable:

```
class Const:
  @property
  def FOO(self):
    return "foo"

CONST = Const()  # You need an instance

if something == CONST.FOO:
  ...
```

With a bit of meta stuff, one can get unsettable attributes with a terse syntax:

```
def const(cls):
    # Replace a class's attributes with properties,
    # and itself with an instance of its doppelganger.
    is_special = lambda name: (name.startswith("__") and name.endswith("__"))
    class_contents = {n: getattr(cls, n) for n in vars(cls) if not is_special(n)}
    def unbind(value):  # Get the value out of the lexical closure.
        return lambda self: value
    propertified_contents = {name: property(unbind(value))
                             for (name, value) in class_contents.items()}
    receptor = type(cls.__name__, (object,), propertified_contents)
    return receptor()  # Replace with an instance, so properties work.


@const
class Paths(object):
    home = "/home"
    null = "/dev/null"
```

Now you can access `Paths.home` as a normal value, but can't assign to it. You can define several classes decorated with `@const`, as you might use several `.h` files.

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this:

Files structure:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    main.py
```

settings.py

```
CONST_A = 'A'
CONST_B = 'B'
```

__init__.py

```
from . import settings as global_settings


class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        for setting in dir(global_settings):
            if setting.isupper():
                setattr(self, setting, getattr(global_settings, setting))

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if not getattr(self, attr, None):
            super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError("'constant' does not support item assignment")


settings = Settings()
```

main.py

```
import settings

print(settings.CONST_A)  # prints A

settings.CONST_A = 'C'  # raises TypeError error

print(settings.CONST_A)  # prints A

settings.CONST_C = 'C'  # also able to add new constants
print(settings.CONST_C)  # prints C
```

Overwritten __setattr__ in *Settings* class makes all the attributes read-only.
The only requirement is to have all the constants in your **settings.py** written in capital letters.
But be aware, that it's not gonna work if you import variables directly:

```
from settings import CONST_A

print(settings.CONST_A)  # prints A

settings.CONST_A = 'C'  # sets C

print(settings.CONST_A)  # prints C
```

Comment: I taken your code as it, __init__ Class giving me error 'indent expected'. After correcting, it's working. Cheers :-)

Comment: Interesting. `import settings` in `main.py` imports the variable `settings` not `settings.py`.

Answer (score 5):

Just define a `constants.py` file and write all your constants. There is no other magic trick in Python. Use **caps** as a general convention.

Comment: Exactly. When in doubt look into Python standard library for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't preprocessed. You can just create a file constant.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
constant.py
"""

MY_CONSTANT = 50
```

Import constant.py file when ever you want constant values like below example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
example.py
"""
import constant
print constant.MY_CONSTANT * 2
```

This way you can use constants across project.

You also have the option, if the constants are tied to a particular class and used privately within that class of making them specific to that class:

```
class Foo(object):
   GOOD = 0
   BAD = 1

   def __init__(self...
```

If you want to define and use entire module, making them on top of the module

```
PIE = 3.47

class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self...
```