# Does Python Support Constants

Tags: python-3.x, constants

i was trying to ask if python supports Contstants?
i was trying but it didn't work

I was expecting if i store 5(or something else) in a Capital word(for exaple: CONSTANT = 5)
it will be constant.

thanks for the attention,
Haroon Zaffar

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 introduces the `typing.Final` type qualifier, which is used to indicate that a variable or attribute should not be reassigned, redefined, or overridden. See link to other StackOverflow answer.

But you do not have constants before that. There are always hacky ways, see link to other StackOverflow answer.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533812/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-constant-variables-python-3)